# Reverse string Python slice notation

Tags: python, python-2.7, slice

```
string = "HELLO"
print string[::-1] #as expected
print string[0:6:-1] #empty string why ?
```

I was amazed to see how easy it is to reverse a string in python but then I struck upon this and got lost. Can someone please explain why the second reverse does not works ?

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Comment: I imagine you want to reverse the indices, too.  See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) for more details.

```python
In [14]: s = 'HELLO'

In [15]: s[6:0:-1]
Out[15]: 'OLLE'
```

Comment: yes I did, couldn't understand that, hence asked here if someone could please explain in simpler terms. I only got the `string[begin:end:step]` thing clear and according to that this should have worked no ?

Comment: Like @dmcdougall said, perhaps you need to reverse the indices.  You're telling the interpreter to start at index 0 and go to (past) the end, but backwards.  You have nothing before the first index.

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation... and I think you can get it working explicitly with `string[4::-1]` but not explicitly specifying the end value also..

Answer (score 1):

The reason the second string is empty is because you are telling the compiler to begin at 0, end at 6 and step -1 characters each time.

Since the compiler will never get to a number bigger than six by repeatedly adding -1 to 0 (it goes 0, -1, -2, -3, ...) the compiler is programmed to return an empty string.

Try `string[6::-1]`, this will work because repeatedly adding -1 to 6 will get to -1 (past the end of the string).

*Note: this is answer is mainly a compilation of @dmcdougall, @Ben_Love and @Sundeep's comments with a bit more explanation*

Answer (score 1):

Slice notation is written as follows:

`list_name[start_index: end_index: step_value]`

The list indexes in python are not like the numbers present on number line. List indexes does not go to `-1st` after `0th` index when `step_value` is `-1`.

Hence below results are produced

`>>>> print string[0:6:-1]`

`>>>>`

And

`>>>> print string[0::-1]`

`>>>> H`

So when the `start_index` is 0, it cant go in a cyclic order to traverse the indexes to -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6 for `step_value` is `-1`.

Similarly

`>>>> print string[-1:-6:-1]`

`>>>> OLLEH`

and

`>>>> print string[-1::-1]`

`>>>> OLLEH`

also

thus when the `start_index` is -1 it goes in a cyclic order to traverse the indexes to -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6 to give output `OLLEH`.

Its pretty straight forward to understand when `start_index` is 6 and `step_value` is -1

`>>>> print string[6::-1]`

`>>>> OLLEH`