# Slicing to reverse a string does not work in this case

Tags: python, slice, reverse

I am a new bee in python. Trying to reverse the string using slicing. It does not work? why?

```
ex='The Man'
reverse = ex[6:-1:-1]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse string Python slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40253256/reverse-string-python-slice-notation)

Answer (score 3):

Just do:

```
ex='The Man'
reverse = ex[::-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
str='The Man' 
stringlength=len(str)
slicedString=str[stringlength::-1] 
print (slicedString)
```

Comment: It's not a good practice to use a data type as a variable name like `str`. Kindly check the edit suggestion. Moreover, the start index in your case is `len(str)`, which, however, doesn't exist. It should be `len(str) - 1`.

Comment: Yes. It would work but you iterating one extra time. Checkout this: https://onlinegdb.com/BkRy-c_br

Answer (score 1):

This is because start index and end index are the same, i.e., 6 and -1 are one and the same index. You should try:

```
ex='The Man'
reverse = ex[6::-1]
```

Comment: How? Is the string  saved in circular array

Comment: You have hard coded the index. What if `ex` value is something like this `stack overflow` ? . Will you do `reverse=ex[13::-1]` ? . Not a good idea though!.

Comment: @VinayHegde This answer was for this specific case. For a generic case, your answer will prove to be a better approach.

Comment: @Randy No. The negative index `i` is equivalent to the index `length of string - absolute value of i `, i.e. in your case `-1` is equivalent to `7 - 1` , i.e. `6`. That's how a negative index is defined. Also here, `ex[6::-1]` means: Start from index 6, decrement `1` at a time up to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
ex='The Man'
reverse = ex[::-1]
```

or

```
ex='The Man'
reverse = ex[-1:-8:-1]
```

Comment: How? Why that -1 and -8

Comment: start index is `-1`, and end index is `-8` of string to be reversed @Randy

Answer (score 1):

```
ex='The Man'
reverse = ex[-1::-1]
```

The index can start from `0` to `len(ex)-1` or `-len(ex)` to `-1`. other index will cause out of range.